# I am having trouble with validation and form wizard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried to add a form wizard with validation. The main problem I am facing is the disable function of the steps doesnt work. When I click on the step numbers on top, it just goes off without any validation.

Here is my html

```
    <div class="x_content">
                    <div class="container">
                            <div class="stepwizard">
                                <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
                                    <div class="stepwizard-step">
                                        <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
                                        <p>Step 1</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="stepwizard-step">
                                        <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
                                        <p>Step 2</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="stepwizard-step">
                                        <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">3</a>
                                        <p>Step 3</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <form role="form">
                            <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <h3> Step 1</h3>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
                                            <input  maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name"  />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                                            <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" />
                                        </div>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <h3> Step 2</h3>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
                                            <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>
                                            <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address"  />
                                        </div>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row setup-content" id="step-3">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <h3> Step 3</h3>
                                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" type="submit">Finish!</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
              </div>
```

My CSS:

```
    .stepwizard-step p {
     margin-top: 10px;
     }

     .stepwizard-row {
     display: table-row;
     }

     .stepwizard {
     display: table;
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     }

     .stepwizard-step button[disabled] {
     opacity: 1 !important;
     filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
     }

     .stepwizard-row:before {
     top: 14px;
     bottom: 0;
     position: absolute;
     content: " ";
     width: 100%;
     height: 1px;
     background-color: #ccc;
     z-order: 0;

     }

    .stepwizard-step {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    }

    .btn-circle {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    border-radius: 15px;
    }
```

The JS:

```
                $(document).ready(function () {

                var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
                allWells = $('.setup-content'),
                allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn');

        allWells.hide();

        navListItems.click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
                    $item = $(this);

            if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
                navListItems.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
                $item.addClass('btn-primary');
                allWells.hide();
                $target.show();
                $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
            }
        });

        allNextBtn.click(function(){
            var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
                curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
                nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
                curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
                isValid = true;

            $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
            for(var i=0; i<curInputs.length; i++){
                if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid){
                    isValid = false;
                    $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
                }
            }

            if (isValid)
                nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
        });

        $('div.setup-panel div a.btn-primary').trigger('click');
    });
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong. How can I get it to work normally.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're checking to see if your $item has a class of disabled which none of them do. However they do have an attribute of disabled. Try !$item.is("[disabled]") instead of !$item.hasClass('disabled')

Answer (score 0):

You are triggering the click event from **`allNextBtn.click(function(){`**.

You may consider [trigger( event [, extraParameters ] )](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) can use extra parameters.

Taking advantage of this you may distinguish if you are triggering from the above function or from the user.

Moreover, before to remove disabled atribute for the next element:

```
nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click', {'isManual': true});
```

you need to add the disabled attribute to all (so only one will be enabled):

```
$('div.setup-panel div a[href^="#"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
```

My snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
      allWells = $('.setup-content'),
      allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn');

  allWells.hide();

  navListItems.click(function (e, isManual) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //
    // test if the click event is ....
    //
    if (($('div.setup-panel div a[disabled]').length == ($('div.setup-panel div a').length - 1)) &&
        (isManual === undefined)) {
      return;
    }


    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
        $item = $(this);

    if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
      navListItems.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
      $item.addClass('btn-primary');
      allWells.hide();
      $target.show();
      $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
    }
  });

  allNextBtn.click(function(){
    var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
        curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
        nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
        curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
        isValid = true;

    $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
    for(var i=0; i<curInputs.length; i++){
      if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid){
        isValid = false;
        $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
      }
    }

    if (isValid) {
      if (nextStepWizard.index(('div.setup-panel div a')) == ($('div.setup-panel div a').length - 1)) {
        //
        // remove the disabled attribute to all
        //
        $('div.setup-panel div a[href^="#"]').removeAttr('disabled');

        nextStepWizard.trigger('click', {'isManual': true});
      } else {
        //
        // add the disabled attribute to all
        //
        $('div.setup-panel div a[href^="#"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        //
        // remove disabled only for the right element
        //
        nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click', {'isManual': true});
      }
    }
  });

  $('div.setup-panel div a.btn-primary').trigger('click', {'isManual': true});
});
```

```css
.stepwizard-step p {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.stepwizard-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.stepwizard {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.stepwizard-step button[disabled] {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}

.stepwizard-row:before {
  top: 14px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  z-order: 0;

}

.stepwizard-step {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="x_content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="stepwizard">
            <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
                <div class="stepwizard-step">
                    <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
                    <p>Step 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="stepwizard-step">
                    <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
                    <p>Step 2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="stepwizard-step">
                    <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">3</a>
                    <p>Step 3</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form role="form">
            <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h3> Step 1</h3>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
                            <input  maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name"  />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                            <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" />
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h3> Step 2</h3>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
                            <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>
                            <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address"  />
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row setup-content" id="step-3">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h3> Step 3</h3>
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" type="submit">Finish!</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works fine now. But the problem is that now, even if we have completed stages one and 2, we cant go back by clicking the stage buttons as that is disabled.

Comment: @Shehzi Snippet updated. When you complete the stage 1 and 2 now you can go back.